# Data structure to delete elements less than k in O(log N) where N is number of elements

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

How should a data structure with the below functions all in O(log N) be implemented?

**insert(x)** - add integer to set

**member(x)** - check if set contains integer x

**delete(x)** - remove the integer x from set

**deleteLessThan(x)**
delete all numbers equal to or less than k

The only thing I can think of is using some kind of balanced BST to obtain the O(log N) for insert, member and delete.

The **deleteLessThan()** function would then look something like: find the smallest element larger than k, delete its left subtree and then rebalance. However, is it possible to rebalance a BST in O(log N) if you delete one of its subtrees?

Comment: Can you phrase this in the form of a question?

Comment: In the heading or will the latest change suffice?

Comment: @arnd, a clearer title is always welcome. I personally would also turn part of the last paragraph into a question as well.

Comment: Assuming an edge case of all nodes < k, then it is impossible tfor deleteLessThan() to function in an O(log(n)) runtime, as it must run at least n deletes.

Comment: Assuming a tree structure with each node individually allocated, that is

Comment: Seems like a splay tree does the job if amortized O(log N) performance is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Is amortised log N good enough? In that case, you can use a splay tree. All operations other than deleting the elements <= k are as explained on Wikipedia. For the remaining operation, splay the smallest element greater than k to the top, and delete its left subtree.

In case you allow amortisation, you can easily account for the deletion of M out of N nodes in O(M) time.